# Rails meta plugin install script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins

I wanna see if there is an approach to pack a few plugins together as a meta plugin that install everything together automatically, works like a project template.

Why not a script? Because I want to put it in github so I don't have to worry about it when I am not with my own PC :) but of coz a script based solution is welcomed too.

Answer (score 1):

My solution (ruby script):

```
plugins = %w{
  http://url_to_plugin_1
  http://url_to_plugin_2
  http://url_to_plugin_3
  http://url_to_plugin_4
  http://url_to_plugin_5
}
plugins.each do | p |
  `ruby script/plugin install -x #{p}`
end
```

run from project root directory

Answer (score 0):

If what you really want is a project template, you might give [templates](http://m.onkey.org/2008/12/4/rails-templates) a try, which is a feature new to 2.3